# "wsl" and "wsl --system" commands reversed?

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hyper-v

I was a happy wsl user for a while, until I've installed Hyper-V.

What I was doing is typing **wsl** in **cmd** and it would launch ubuntu and I could do what I needed in there.

Now, after I've rebooted, wsl command will instead run something else. The command prompt is for **wsgl**, not **root**, and the system contents are different. **cat/etc/os-release** shows:

```
 NAME="Common Base Linux Mariner".
```

Even weirder still, running **wsl --system** will run my Ubuntu! os-release will show PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS" and everything works fine

I also have no other distros installed. **wsl --list** gives:

```
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
Ubuntu (Default)
```

How can I revert it back to make wsl call my Ubuntu and not this whatever it is?

Comment: WSL1 or WSL2? `wsl -l -v`

Answer (score 0):

If you run `wsl --list --all` then one entry will have "(Default)" next to it.  That will be the default distro entered when just running `wsl`.

```
>wsl --list --all
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
Debian (Default)
kali-linux
```

You can change this with `wsl --setdefault <distroname>`.

```
>wsl --setdefault kali-linux
The operation completed successfully.

>wsl --list --all
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
kali-linux (Default)
Debian
```

Alternatively you can normally pick the distro by running the specific command; e.g. `debian` will enter the Debian distro; `kali` will enter the Kali distro, and so on.